# How can I prevent jQuery's .val() element method from applying decimals with a comma instead of a dot for number type fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, localization

This may have to do with browser localisation or something. I'm applying this in South Africa (where the default separator for decimal place *should* be a dot but for some crazy reason seems to be a comma).

The problem:

**This HTML**

```
<input id="my-input" type="number" value="1" />
```

**... with this jQuery script**

```
$('#my-input').val(2.5);
```

... yields an input displaying "2,5" in it (which when inspected shows the "value" attribute as having a value of "1")

Here it is illustrated:

```js
$('#my-input').val(2.5);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" value="1" id="my-input" />
```

Comment: The number format is specified by the locale of the client, I don't believe you have any control over it from JS. All you could do is change the field type to `text` and then write you own code to add the behaviour of a `number` input